# should enum's contain None?

Tags: c#, coding-style, enums

I have sometimes seen `enum`s like this:

```
public enum Color {
    None, Black, Red, Blue
}
```

with code like:

```
Color color;

...

if (color == Color.None) ...
```

I would prefer using a nullable enum and code it like this:

```
public enum Color {
    Black, Red, Blue
}

...

Color? color;

...

if (color == null) ...
```

Which style is preferred?

Comment: `None` over `null`. `None` makes it more than obvious to guess.

Comment: "I would prefer using a nullable enum "... not to be a wise-ass, but it sounds like you answered your own question. The answer depends on the intent behind the enum to begin with. If it's something that should be NULL at times, then make it nullable. If it should never be NULL, add the "None" option.

Comment: Usually the first one. It makes for easier debugging purposes, plus `null` is not the same as `Color.None`.

Comment: @Chuck, you are "begging the question".  It can sometimes not have a value in the domain.  But should the code represent it as None or null?

Comment: @David, I know they are not the same.  If I use a Nullable enum, I won't include None in the enum.  I'm not planning to ever have both possibilities

Comment: @JoelFan But setting `color` to null is the same as saying that it's not applicable, while setting it to `Color.None` is saying that it doesn't have a color at that moment.

Comment: @AniketInge: I tend to disagree. Without `None`, `Color` means _"a valid color"_, and `Color?` means _"either a valid color, xor no valid color"_. It even encodes it in the type, so that information is available everywhere. Of course we still have to look at each enum's definition, because otherwise we don't know whether it has a `None` or not, which is a pity.

Comment: @SebastianMach I tend to avoid nulls for the dreaded Null Ref exception. Nulls have their special place in programming, but I tend to minimize them as much as possible AND use the Null Object pattern. I guess it's a matter of taste and choice.

Comment: @AniketInge: And Nones have there special place in programming, too. I really don't always want to check if a `Color` is valid or not, but instead only if it's explicitly optional. Maybe I'm so strict because I have a C++-background, we can value-type (almost) everything and make proper use of that, and we strive for exception safety. Many functions cannot be coded strongly exception safe in presence of a potential `None`, in other words: A function accepting an enum which has `None` either has to fall back to default values, or exceptions. `None` significantly increases receiver's complexity.

Answer (score 13):

As ever, it depends.

For a `[Flags]` enum, a `None` value is almost always a good idea, as "none of these options" is a useful concept. For a non-`[Flags]` enum, I wouldn't usually include a `None` value unless it was obviously conceptually useful.

That said, the [enum guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229058%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as part of "Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries" include:

> Do provide a value of zero on simple enumerations.
>
> If possible, name this value None. If None is not appropriate, assign the value zero to the most commonly used value (the default).

... although the examples don't include `None`, and many enums in the .NET framework don't have `None` values either...

As for whether you should use a nullable enum or not - it really depends on the situation. I *would* use a `Color?` variable for "there may be a `Color` value, or there may not be" because `None` really *isn't* a sensible colour. *Not* having `None` means that `Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Color))` is more useful, IMO. Why would enums be different to any other non-nullable value type? You wouldn't normally use 0 for "we don't have any information" - you'd use an `int?` instead. I'd suggest treating enums in a manner consistent with how you'd treat `int`.

(Having said all of this, I see that I include `None` as a value in `IsoDayOfWeek` in Noda Time, which I find surprising, looking at it right now.)

Comment: I don't see how int is comparable to enum.  There is no way to add more values to int so there is no choice but to make it nullable.  With an enum there is the option to add a None value. BTW, I have seen lots of code where 0 in an int means "no information" and I HATE that!

Comment: @JoelFan: Well often you could say "-1 (or `int.MinValue`) isn't a valid normal value for this variable, so we'll use that as an absence value" - it's just ugly IMO.

Comment: I would only use int.MinValue if I was going to take advantage of comparability... i.e. if I'm computing a maximum, it makes sense to initialize it to int.MinValue

Comment: A similar question that comes up for me is whether to use a Nullable DateTime or DateTime.MinValue

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would avoid something like `None` as a Color. None obviously is not a color, and it is therefore semantically not correct. Whenever that happens you run into trouble.

E.g. try and imagine a `Set` of possible colors. `[ White, Black, Red ]` makes sense, but obviously `[ White, Black, None ]` doesn't.

`null` would be preferable, although you could also try and work around the issue, e.g. a `isPresent()` method or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is the meaning you want to give to `None`.

`null` is unknown, null can be any color  or with no color, but we don't know the color.
While None sounds as the color is known to be: absent of a color.

So..pick the right thing for you application.

Comment: `null` is how the absence of any other value is handled for *every other type* (so for `int`, you'd use `int?` to be a variable which could be "no known value"). Why would you treat enums differently?

Comment: When you said you'd treat `None` (a value of type `Color`) as a value meaning the *absence* of a color. That's like using `DateTime.MinValue` as a magic value to be like null for `DateTime`, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet,no it means that `None` == transparent or something like it, no magic value, just no color(if it has meaning in real life it's for another question.)

Comment: I view "transparent" as "not a colour" - that's the difference here. I wouldn't want it as part of the enum. Possibly colour is an unfortunate example here.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Now I see. Yes, color isn't a good example, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

`None` over `null`. `None` makes it more than obvious to guess. And you can use it like this: `colorObject.None`. But this is subjective and based on tastes.

There is no `color` called "null" but there can be a no-`color`(transparent?).

Comment: The notion of "no color" is as physically plausible as "null color". Even if no color is perceived on a surface, there are still photons travelling, and whether there is "no" color outside of the visible spectrum is not to be judged by the human eye. Also, `null`, `nil`, `nul` and all other forms are widely agreed on, meaning "there is no pointee/target/value".

Comment: Furthermore, it's not just about taste, as in _comprehension of something being `null` or `none`_, but also about forcing liabilities and worse degrees of exception safety/worse style onto all code which use the type. E.g., liability: All code must check against `none`. E.g., exception safety: Code that otherwise throws no exceptions now must throw an exception in case of `None`, or fall back to default values, or reduce postconditional guarantees (e.g. instead of `returns the grayscale counterpart of Color x`, one has to use `returns the grayscale counterpart of Color x, or None if x==None`).

Answer (score 0):

If it's valid for whatever object you're setting the color of to not have a color I think you should have None as an option, otherwise leave it off.

Comment: assume it's valid to not have a color.  Please answer the question if I should handle it with None or null

Comment: Since it's valid for the object to not have a color I would have None as an option.